# Facebook menu button css

Tags: css

[image]

I have tried this css code for menu button, but its not look like the one which i wanted, can any one help me out in this.

```
button.menu
{
  background: #e3e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f6f6f6;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f6f6f6;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f6f6f6;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px 0px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  width: 45px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:15px;
  font-family:Segoe UI Semibold, Calibri;
  margin-top:-1.5px;
```

}

```
 button.menu:active
 {
   background: #d0d0d0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #e3e3e3;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #e3e3e3;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #e3e3e3;
   color: black;
 }
```

Comment: Heya. It helps if you're more specific, include some code you tried in the question, and tell us what the specific problem with it is. Note that you can edit your question at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your buttons an inner shadow with ccs like this:

```
.shadow {-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000; box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;}
```

the text may have a text-shadow which is not supported by IE

```
.text-shadow {text-shadow: #c0c0c0 3px 3px 5px;}
```

to achieve the rounded edges you have to use

```
#example1 {-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;}
```

Hope it helps you build your menu!